# I want to convert the value of my label into Time hh/mm/ss

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net2008 I have **TWO LABEL**. **Label1** is my Fines and **Label2** is for Time(hh/mm/ss). Every value of my Label1 (Fines) will convert into my Label2 (Time).

If my Label1 has a value of 25 it will convert 30minutes in my Label2 (Time). And if becomes 50 it will add into my Label2 (Time) and the Label2 will become 1 hour.

Comment: `25` to `30 Minutes` or `00:30:00`  ?

Comment: `00:30:00` sir and 50 is `01:00:00`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean 25 --> 30  (Fine * 1.2 = Time)

```
Dim dtDate as date = #01/01/1905#
Label2.Text =  dtDate.AddMinutes(Cint(Label1.text) * 1.2).toString("HH/mm/ss")
```